# How to find the most recent version of a file in a git repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a file in a Git Repository with many branches. This fill gets updated and expanded frequently. When I modify the file I forget to check on which branch I am, so that it could happen, that the file has 100 lines but I'm changing the version of a file that has 50 lines and is old.
Is there a way to find out where that file lives in a branch that has the most recent changes?

I know that I can use `git checkout branchname -- file.ext` but how can I find out the brach name?

Or better: Is there a way to share one file among **all** branches? So that all branches share always the same version of a **specific** file?

Comment: Branches are temporary pointers to a commit. Commits are a snapshot of the entire repo, not just a change or one file. For all branches to "share" the same file, either they all need to point to the same commit, or the same file must exist in all commits that the branches point to.

Comment: That means when I change the file, I need to update every commit?

Comment: Most recent across different branch is not obvious, if you really need to share a file across branches remove it from the repository and use a different repository. But seems very weird to me. Perhaps add helper to know on which branch you are working can be a better solution

Comment: @PeterPan Absolutely not. When you change a file and you commit it, then this change exists in the current branch. Then cherry-pick the commit elsewhere or merge the branch if other branches need this same change.

Comment: What do you mean by "update every commit"? Once made, a commit cannot be updated. Commands like cherry-pick/amend only create new commits, the old ones are still there.

Comment: I don't know if I get all of this right. I search a solution for "Hey git, search every branch that has the file foo.ext and update the file with the changes that I am currently doing".

Answer (score 1):

You're starting by putting yourself in a very bad position, like trying to win the Kentucky Derby by getting yourself an emu in Australia rather than a horse in the USA.  The problem is simple enough: a branch in Git *does not have files*.  In fact, in an important sense, branches don't even *exist* in Git!

Of course that's nonsense—branches do exist—but the problem is that the word *branch* does not have one particular single meaning.  So until you specify which *kind* of "branch" you mean, the word branch doesn't mean anything at all.  We might as well make up a word like "cryosome" or "trajectomy" or something.  The options for defining "branch" here might be *branch name* (these don't have files), *remote-tracking (branch) name* (these also don't have files), *DAGlet* (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)), or *branch tip*.

This last one actually gets us somewhere!  A *branch tip* has files!  But another word for *branch tip* would be *commit*.  It's the commit, in Git, that has files.  Every commit has a full snapshot of *every* file, frozen in time for all eternity.<sup>1</sup>  These files literally can't be changed though: instead of changing the files in some existing commit, what we do is:

1. extract some existing commit into an area in which we *can* change files;
2. change some file(s) in this changeable area; and
3. make a *new commit* from the resulting (changed) files, making a new permanent, unchangeable snapshot.

Every commit we make has a unique<sup>2</sup> hash ID: that big ugly string of letters-and-digits that you can't remember.  No human can deal with these, so we don't.  We have *Git* remember the *latest* one from some particular thing-we-call-a-branch using a thing-we-call-a-branch.  We branch the branch and branch branch branchity branch branch, branch-branch, branch?  Er, sorry, I got Git-ified and all words became "branch".   (This is the problem with the word *branch* and Git's enormous overuse of it.)

Anyway, let's take a look at *commits*—the things that actually matter in Git—and see if there is a way for you to solve your actual problem.  We'll see how Git uses branch names to *find* commits, too.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or at least, for as long as the commit continues to exist.  It's possible, sometimes, to remove a commit from a repository.  (GitHub generally won't, and it's tricky to do in regular Git.)

<sup>2</sup>The hash ID here is required to be *truly* unique, as in, no other Git repository *anywhere in the universe* is allowed to use the hash ID you just got for your new commit, unless it's being used to store *that commit* (that they get from you, or from some other repository that got it from you).  That's why the hash IDs are so big and ugly, so that they can be unique.  This is mathematically impossible (see the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)), so Git will someday stop working.  The size of the hash puts that day far enough in the future—trillions of years or more, we hope—that, we hope, we're all so long dead and gone that nobody cares.

---

#### How commits and names work

Every commit:

- is numbered, with a big ugly hash ID;
- stores a full snapshot of all of your files; and
- also stores some *metadata:* information about the commit itself.

I mentioned the first two of these already, but let's look at the third one a little more closely.  When you make a new commit, Git uses your `user.name` and `user.email` settings to record *you* as the *author* (and committer) of the new commit.  It uses your computer's clock to get the current date-and-time, and puts those in the new commit.  Git makes you enter a *commit message* (with `-m` or via an editor or something) and stores that message along with the commit.

All of this stuff is part of the *metadata* for the commit: the information *about* the commit that's not the snapshot itself.  Git adds, in this metadata, a *list of previous commit hash IDs*.  For most commits—the ones we'll look at here—this list has exactly one entry in it; Git calls this one hash ID the *parent* of this new commit.  But it's a list, so it can be any number, from none at all to lots; it's just that "one" is the most common number of list-entries per commit.

The effect of storing one hash ID in the commit's metadata is to make the new commit point backwards to its parent.  That is, the parent has a unique hash ID, and the new commit has a unique hash ID, and the new commit connects to the parent:

```
a123456   <--b789abc
```

for instance.  The hash IDs are too big and ugly for human brains to handle, though, so we'll use uppercase letters, like this:

```
              G <-H
```

to stand in for whatever hash IDs Git might really use.  Commit `H` here is thus your newest (hence latest) commit, and inside `H`, in its metadata, Git has stored the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  So Git can use `H` to *find* `G`.

But `G` is a commit, so it too has a parent hash ID.  That means `G` points backwards to some earlier commit `F`:

```
          F <-G <-H
```

and of course `F` points backwards too, and so on, forever, or at least until we get to the very first commit:

```
A <-... <-F <-G <-H
```

which can't point backwards, so it has an empty list.

The metadata, like everything in every commit, is frozen for all time, so if some commit points backwards to some earlier commit, it does so forever.  Commits also can't point *forwards* to the *next* commit because the hash ID that you'll get depends on things like the exact time at which you will make the future commit.  Git has no idea when that will be, or what will be in it, so commits can *only* point backwards.  As a result, we can be lazy when we draw them, and I will.

Now let's add a *branch name*, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- somebranch
```

The branch name `somebranch` simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the branch.  So the name `somebranch` points to `H` at the moment.  If and when we make a *new* commit, though, the new commit will point backwards to `H`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

and Git will immediately *update the branch name*—unlike commits, Git *can* change the hash ID stored in a *name*—so that it now points to new commit `I`, which means we don't need to draw `I` on a separate line after all:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- somebranch
```

You might now say: *Aha, so I just want to check every branch name's commit!*  Yes: this could be what you want!  Alas, but no: it's probably not what you want, after all.  You see, *branch* names are not the only names that select commits.  Besides *branch* names, we also have *tag* names and *remote-tracking names*.

A *tag* name is a name for a commit, like a branch name.  But unlike a branch name, a tag name normally never moves.  We have Git create a tag name when we have some particularly important commit—such as a release version—that we want people to be able to name, now and forever, without having to memorize some random-looking hash ID.  Do you want to look at tag names?  Maybe, maybe not: this will depend on how you *use* tag names.

The bigger thorn here is the *remote-tracking name*.  A remote-tracking name is your own Git repository's way of remembering some *other* Git repository's *branch* name.  We just saw how, if you're on your branch `somebranch` and make a *new* commit, *your* branch name `somebranch` changes its stored value, so that it points *to* the new commit.  If someone else, in another clone, has a branch named `somebranch` and *they* make a new commit, *their* repository will update *their* `somebranch` name to point to this other new commit.

Let's suppose this sort of thing does happen.  That is, you make new commits in your repository on branch `develop`, and Alice or Bob or Chandra or Darius makes new commits in *their* repository on `develop` too.  At some point you'll pick up *their* commit(s), while you have your own commit(s) that you have added.  The result looks like this:

```
          I   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- origin/develop
```

Which of these is the *latest* commit?  Remember that they made their new commit `J` not knowing of your commit `I`, and vice versa, and perhaps you and they made these same commits at the exact same second, just on different computers.  Even if you were seconds or minutes apart, you're both "latest", so you can't go by *time*.

Ultimately, there's no single answer here.  This is why merges exist in Git: sometimes we have no choice but to *combine* work done by two different people or groups, but done in parallel "at the same time".  **If this applies to your situation, you're using the wrong approach.**  But if not, you might well be able to use all the branch and/or remote-tracking names to find the latest commits *on* those "branches" (whatever we mean by branch here), and use those to inspect the file(s) in question.

#### Your other question

> Or better: Is there a way to share one file among **all** branches? So that all branches share always the same version of a **specific** file?

We can already see that the answer to that is a definite "no".  There are, really, only *commits* in Git.  The branch names, and other names, are just ways to find particular commits, and each name finds one commit and then those commits hold frozen-for-all-time snapshots.  If they do share one particular version of a file—which happens all the time in Git—then Git makes sure that they *literally* share that file's content, so that it's stored just once in the repository.  (Git does this by automatically *de-duplicating* all content.)  But they either identify the same commit, in which case they have the same content for that file, or they identify different commits, in which case they *might or might not* have the same content for that file and you'll have to check.  There's no one right way to determine which one is the *latest* though, and there may be no way at all.

#### A possible alternative, but think hard before you use it

One thing you *can* do is that instead of storing this file as a regular tracked file at all, where it's committed inside *every* branch, you can declare that this particular file is *untracked* in all branches (and you'll list it in `.gitignore` so that it stays that way).  That way it's not stored in *any* of these commits.  Meanwhile, you have one dedicated branch name—which still requires dealing with remote-tracking names, and merging if other people have made commits—in which you store, not a file named `xyzzy.untracked`, but rather one named `xyzzy.master-copy`.  To update this file, you check out the `xyzzy` branch, which stores *only* this one file:

```
git worktree add ../xyzzy  # if this is the first time using it
cd ../xyzzy
... edit the xyzzy.master-copy file ...
git add xyzzy.master-copy
git commit
cd ../normal-work-area
cp ../xyzzy/xyzzy.master-copy xyzzy.untracked
```

Now, since `xyzzy.untracked` literally *is* untracked, it never goes into any new commits.  `xyzzy.master-copy` doesn't go in these commits either: you keep it only in the `xyzzy` commits, on the `xyzzy` branch.  You never edit that file in the place where you normally work, since it doesn't even *exist* there.  It only exists in the added working tree with the `xyzzy` branch in it.

To *make* the `xyzzy` branch initially, you can check out the very first commit you ever made in your repository (find it with `git log --max-parents=0` for instance) as a detached-HEAD commit, then create a new branch name:

```
git switch -c xyzzy
```

Remove any files you don't want to leave around here and create the "master copy" file with some initial content.  Add and commit it.  Then switch back to the branch you will normally work on/with, and notice that `xyzzy.master-copy` no longer exists in your working area.  Add `xyzzy.untracked` to `.gitignore` to make sure you don't accidentally extract it, then use `git show xyzzy:xyzzy.master-copy > xyzzy.untracked`, or use the `git worktree add` trick to add a working tree, or whatever you like.

(You can, instead of finding your root commit, use `git switch --orphan xyzzy`.  This will set things up so that your *next* commit makes the "orphan branch" by making a second root commit in your repository.  This method is a little confusing to those not steeped in graph theory and/or Git, though.)

Note that now that you have just the one-file-in-one-branch, you have a problem: should you ever discover that you actually *need two different versions of `xyzzy.untracked`*, you cannot get that.  There's a reason Git makes this hard: it's almost certainly the wrong thing to do.